# Why my webview covered popup in metro app?

Tags: popup, microsoft-metro

I want to make a setting panel in my metro app.

I added a main page with webview like this:

```
<Page
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:App"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
x:Class="App.MainPage"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <WebView x:Name="MainWebView"/>
</Grid>
```

and use this code to display my popip window

```
   _settingsPopup = new Popup();
        _settingsPopup.Closed += OnPopupClosed;
        Window.Current.Activated += OnWindowActivated;
        _settingsPopup.IsLightDismissEnabled = true;
        _settingsPopup.Width = _settingsWidth;
        _settingsPopup.Height = _windowBounds.Height;

        SettingsPanel mypane = new SettingsPanel();
        mypane.Width = _settingsWidth;
        mypane.Height = _windowBounds.Height;

        _settingsPopup.Child = mypane;
        _settingsPopup.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, _windowBounds.Width - _settingsWidth);
        _settingsPopup.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, 0);
        _settingsPopup.IsOpen = true;
```

but, finally the popup can't be displayed and when i set the webview to be hidden ,I found the popup behind the webview.

I can't found any function or properties to set the zindex or sth like zindex to help me taking the popup to the front.

How can I make it correct?

Answer (score 1):

The behavior is by design as the `WebView` will always assume the topmost position. The recommended solution is to either hide the `WebView` as you popup, or to use the `WebViewBrush` as a placeholder when your popup is displayed.

There are lots of tutorials on the web, I personally recommend this article:
[How to display charms on a top of the WebView](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/priozersk/archive/2012/08/13/how-to-display-charms-on-a-top-of-the-webview.aspx)